# Why is csv.Dictreader reading only the first row/column?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, keyerror

I want to read a csv file into my Tkinter application and split the content of the file in different widgets. I am able to read and enter the text of the first column into the correct entry widget but it fails to continue. I receive a 'KeyError:' exception.

My example code which is just an isolated block to see whether I can print the file content:

```
import csv

with open("bible.csv", mode="r") as file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in csv_reader:
        x = row["title"]
        y = row["author"]
        z = row["year"]
```

The error message is:

> ```
> Bible
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/Users/", line 23, in <module>
> y = row['author']
> KeyError: 'author'
> ```

The CSV content is just this:

```
title, author, year, others, note
Bible,Many,0,Religion,This is the bible.
```

**Can somebody please explain why it only takes the first 'row' and does not continue?**

Thank you very much for your insides!

Comment: Er, did you mean 'insights'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The headers are being read with their intial spaces, so the key is `" author"` instead of `"author"`.  You can set the [`skipinitialspace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.skipinitialspace) formatting parameter to `True` to prevent this

```
import csv

with open("bible.csv", mode="r") as file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(file, skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in csv_reader:
        x = row["title"]
        print(x)
        y = row['author']
        z = row["year"]
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much for your answer. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

The error `KeyError: 'author'` means that the key `"author"` isn't present in `row`. Sure enough, if we add `print(row)`, we see:

```
OrderedDict([('title', 'Bible'), (' author', 'Many'), (' year', '0'), (' others', 'Religion'), (' note', 'This is the bible.')])
```

So the key is actually `" author"` rather than `"author"`. Patrick Haugh provides a workaround for this in his answer.